# Cannot send json to server, an ajax error occurs

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I tried this code on my site, then on other site, then on jquery.com via console:

```
jQuery.ajax({
url: '/',
type: 'POST',
data: '{"test":"test"}',
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
dataType: 'json'
});

$(document).ajaxError(function(e, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError){
    console.log(thrownError);
});
```

So the console logs this:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

I don't understand why. It looks that everything is correct in my code.

Comment: unquote data it should be `data: {test:"test"}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing a string literal rather than an object:

```
data: { test: 'test' },
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a typo in Line 4

Try:

```
data: {test:"test"},
```

And it should work - I hope :)

<sup>Sorry, i had the 3 Minutes 1 Post Problem here and wasn't able to see the comment from Victory</sup>